# What's the purpose of these Java files in scala.runtime?

Tags: java, scala, programming-languages, reference, runtime

There are a few *.java files in the source tree of Scala in the [scala.runtime](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/master/src/library/scala/runtime) directory.

Those files seem to be very simple, e. g. `DoubleRef.java` looks like this:

```
package scala.runtime;

public class DoubleRef implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8304402127373655534L;

    public double elem;
    public DoubleRef(double elem) { this.elem = elem; }
    public String toString() { return java.lang.Double.toString(elem); }
}
```

Is there any reason why those classes can't be defined in Scala?

Comment: Just a guess. There is no Scala construct would compile to private static field, and maybe this is required by java.io.Serializable to work correctly?

Comment: @Brian: You would use `@SerialVersionUID` annotation for that instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a guess, too: there is no Scala construct that compiles to a public field — public `var`s in Scala compile to a private field and to a public accessor and mutator. As I imagine that those `*Ref` classes are used extensively, this could be an optimization to avoid frequent method calls and replace them with direct field access.

Comment: That sounds plausible, but wouldn't declaring those methods `final` get the same effect by letting Java optimize them out?

Comment: I don't know — maybe the idea is to not require anyone (compiler or JVM) to do any optimization here...